# ExtJs 4.2 view.view change itemSelector

Tags: extjs

I have

> Ext.XTemplate

like this

```
<div class="">
<div style = "width:100%;height:170px;" class="">
   <div>
           <a class="my-class" href="javascript:void(0)">text</a>
         <a class="my-class" href="javascript:void(0)" >text</a>
    </div>
</div>              
</div>
```

and items selector

> itemSelector: 'a.my-class',
>   i what this but it only works 
>   'div.some-class'

Comment: Have you tried `a.my-class`?

Comment: yes , but it does not work , there is error: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: You must have only one element with this class per record.